# a4j:ajax keyup event not working

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

After a long time I'm using a4j:ajax to get simple text from h:inputText and render to h:outputText but it's not working

I found many examples like [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=ajax&skin=blueSky) but none of them worked for me.

this id my bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean(name="usertest")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {

    private String name = "john";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and this is my index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<body>

<h:form id="f1">
    <h:inputText id="name1" value="#{usertest.name}">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="name2" execute="@form"></a4j:ajax>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="name2" value="#{usertest.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4.0
Any solution would help me.

Tanks

Comment: What's the `execute="@form"` for? The example works without it.

Comment: Best to start ajax operations with `@ViewScoped`, not `@RequestScoped`